# What does this regex in php mean?

Tags: php, regex

Can somebody please explain me what this regex means?

```
#<hr(.*)class="system-pagebreak"(.*)\/>#iU
```

Is there a tool to convert these regular expresions to normal words?

Comment: This tool very clearly explains each symbol(token) http://regex101.com/. You may have to seperate flags and delimiters first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex matches any self-closing hr with class "sytem-pagebreak", but not with additional classes.

the "actual" regex is the part between `#`
the `iU` behind that is two "flags" specifying, how the regex will behave. the `i` means that the regex will be case-insensitive, the `U` means that the regex qualifiers are lazy by default.

the first part of the regex (`<hr`) will be evaluated as a String literal. it matches any combination like:

```
- <hr
- <Hr
- <hR
- <HR
```

then follows a group evaluation (marked by the `()`). Evaluated will be the special char `.` (any character) that will be matched as many times as it goes.

then follows a literal string evaluation for `class="system-pagebreak"`. This will **not** match things like these:

- class="system-pagebreak someclass"
- class ="system-pagebreak"

after that there is again any char as often as it comes and then a literal match for `/>`. The backslash is just for escaping the slash from the regex (as it is also a special char).

Answer (score 6):

It is attempting* to match any `<hr>` tags that have `class="system-pagebreak"` attributes.

The `(.*)` segments between `hr` and `class` and the closing `/>` match "zero or more characters", so it can match things like

```
<hr id="what" class="system-pagebreak" style="display:block" />
```

The `#iU` at the end make it case-insensitive (`i`) and ungreedy (`U`) so that the `.*` matches won't eat up the whole document.

> Is there a tool to convert these regular expresions to normal words?

Not really? What can you mean by "normal words"? That's a very straight forward regex, and you can't "convert" it to anything else without losing its meaning. There are plenty of sites for *testing* regular expressions though, such as [Regex101](http://regex101.com/).

*Note that I say *attempting* because this is a *really bad* way of attempting to interact with (X)HTML, and is sure to break eventually. You should use a [DOM-parser](https://www.php.net/book.dom).

Comment: and here comes the standard link to the ages old answer on parsing html with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

It will match `<hr>` tags with `class="system-pagebreak"` attribute. It will also capture anything between hr and class and between the second quotation mark and the end of the tag (`/>`). / escapes the slash. i makes it insensitive and U ungreedy. The pound (#) signs mark the beginning and end of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a tool to convert these regular expresions to normal words?

You can use a tool like [www.regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com/) to visualize the regex: [http://www.regexper.com/#%23%3Chr(.*)class%3D%22system-pagebreak%22(.*)%5C%2F%3E%23](http://www.regexper.com/##%3Chr%28.%2a%29class=%22system-pagebreak%22%28.%2a%29%5C/%3E#) This helps understandig it.

> Can somebody please explain me what this regex means?

There are already enough good answers :)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match all characters on the same line after `<hr` until `class="system-pagebreak"` will be met, and put it in the first capturing group. And then, it will put all characters (always on the same line) in the capturing group 2 until `/>`

The goal is probably to find self closing hr tags that contains the class `system-pagebreak`. However it's a bad pattern since it will match too this kind of string:

```
<hr><div class="system-pagebreak"><img src="image.jpg" />
```